# passing data from a Service to another

Tags: android, service, android-intent

I have two services:
a provider of data and a receiver.

i try to do this way:

PROVIDER:

```
Intent i1 = new Intent(feasibilityEngine.this, SOSFeeder.class);
i1.putExtra(SENSOR_STRING, "f[i]");
startService(i1);
```

RECEIVER

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
int i = b.getInt(SENSRO_STRING);
```

but i can't use the getIntent().

Someone can help me?
TNKS

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the value of SENSRO_STRING as:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
int i = b.getInt(SENSRO_STRING);
```

If you are in a BroadcastReceiver for example, in the overwritten `onReceived` method, you can call as:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
     Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
     int i = b.getInt(SENSRO_STRING);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to call getInent(), Your intent will be handed to the receiver service in the onStartCommand(), which will be your entry point from a startService() call.

*sample code modified from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29)*.

Receiver Service:

```
// This is the old onStart method that will be called on the pre-2.0
// platform.  On 2.0 or later we override onStartCommand() so this
// method will not be called.
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    handleCommand(intent);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handleCommand(intent);
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void handleCommand(Intent intent) {
    // should this be getStringExtra instead?
    int i = intent.getIntExtra(SENSRO_STRING, -1);
}
```